# Cでシステムコールプログラミング

Tags: c

C言語でシステムコールプログラミングをしようとしています。[*1]

http://www.atmarkit.co.jp/ait/articles/1112/13/news117.html
そこで、上のサイトを参考に（正確にはコピペ）プログラムを実行しようとしました。

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
int
main(void)
{
    int fdi, fdo;
    char b[1];
    fdi = open("in", O_RDONLY);
    fdo = open("out", O_WRONLY);
    while (0 < read(fdi, b, 1)) {
        write(fdo, b, 1);
    }
    close(fdi);
    close(fdo);
}
```

上のプログラムのopenのところでエラーになってしまいます。
なにか、多分インクルードファイルが少ないのだと思うのですがどのように解決したらいいですか。

<sup>*1: 正確には、コンパイラはC++ですがCの機能だけを使う予定です。</sup>

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C' に入ります
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/c_____
make[2]: ディレクトリ `/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C' に入ります
mkdir -p build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228
rm -f "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228/02.o.d"
g++    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228/02.o.d" -o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228/02.o /home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C/問題4-X/02.cpp
mkdir -p dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86
g++     -o dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/c_____ build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228/01.o build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228/02.o 
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228/02.o: 関数 `main' 内:
/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C/問題4-X/02.cpp:11: `main' が重複して定義されています
build/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/_ext/986599228/01.o:/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C/問題4-X/01.cpp:17: ここで最初に定義されています
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/GNU-Linux-x86/c_____] エラー 1
make[2]: ディレクトリ `/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C' から出ます
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] エラー 2
make[1]: ディレクトリ `/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C' から出ます
make: *** [.build-impl] エラー 2

ビルド FAILED (終了値2, 合計時間: 213ms)
```

Comment: 実際のエラーメッセージを提示していただけると原因追究が早くなるとおもいます。エラーはコンパイルエラーですか？ランタイムエラーですか？

Comment: 一つのプロジェクトに別の問題（ライブラリの方）も一緒に記述していませんか？プロジェクトを分ければうまくいくと思います。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

複数ソースコードがコンパイルされてしまって、それぞれにmain()があってシンボルの重複でリンクエラーになってる気がします。。
/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C/問題4-X/01.cpp
/home/aaa/NetBeansProjects/C/問題4-X/02.cpp

インクルードするヘッダファイルは合っていると思います。
NetBeansはわからないのですが、そのソースコード単体をgccでコマンドラインでビルドすると通りませんか？